# How to get Linux commands history in Splunk without Splunk Forwarder?

Tags: linux, active-directory, bash, splunk

We have tons of Linux machines which are all connected to Active Directory (AD). AD logs are being pulled in Splunk.

Is there a way to get the command history of all Linux machines in Splunk from AD logs (more like processes command line logs for Windows) without installing a Splunk forwarder in each one of them?

Comment: According [Choosing a Forwarder, or not](https://www.splunk.com/blog/2011/10/24/choosing-a-forwarder-or-not.html) and [Getting data in](http://dev.splunk.com/view/SP-CAAAE3A#Gettingdatain-Specifyingyourinputsource), a forwarder seems to be recommended. I don't know a practicable way of pulling logs from tons of Linux machines in Splunk.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to system syslog to a central syslog server, and running single Splunk Forwarder there. You could then bulk ingest logs, or only ingest logs for the systems you want. It also makes it a little easier to grow down the road as you can have any additional processes just syslog to the same server.